# Change the underlying data representation with the descriptor protocol

Tags: python

Suppose I have an existing class, for example doing some mathematical stuff:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = y
        self.y = y

    def norm(self):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(self.x, 2) + math.pow(self.y, 2))
```

Now, for some reason, I'd like to have that Python does not store the members `x` and `y` like any variable. I'd rather want that Python internally stores them as strings. Or that it stores them into a dedicated buffer, maybe for interoperability with some C code. So (for the string case) I build the following *descriptor*:

```
class MyStringMemory(object):

    def __init__(self, convert):
        self.convert = convert

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Read')
        return self.convert(self.prop)

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Write')
        self.prop = str(val)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        print('Delete')
```

And I wrap the existing vector class in a new class where members `x` and `y` become `MyStringMemory`:

```
class StringVector(Vector):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    x = MyStringMemory(float)
    y = MyStringMemory(float)
```

Finally, some driving code:

```
v = StringVector(1, 2)
print(v.norm())
v.x, v.y = 10, 20
print(v.norm())
```

After all, I replaced the internal representation of `x` and `y` to be strings without any change in the original class, but still with its full functionality.

I just wonder: **Will that concept work universally or do I run into serious pitfalls?** As I said, the main idea is to store the data into a specific buffer location that is later on accessed by a C code.

**Edit:** The intention of what I'm doing is as follows. Currently, I have a nicely working program where some physical objects, all of type `MyPhysicalObj` interact with each other. The code *inside* the objects is vectorized with Numpy. Now I'd also like to vectorize some code *over all* objects. For example, each object has an `energy` that is computed by a complicated vectorized code per-object. Now I'd like to sum up all energies. I can iterate over all objects and sum up, but that's slow. So I'd rather have that property `energy` for each object automatically stored into a globally predefined buffer, and I can just use `numpy.sum` over that buffer.

Comment: If you want interoperability with C code have a look at Numpy and Cython. You can send Numpy buffers to C/C++ through cython. I wouldn't transform numbers to strings, is a very inneficient representation.

Answer (score 1):

There is one pitfall regarding python descriptors.

Using your code, you will reference the same value, stored in StringVector.x.prop and StringVector.y.prop respectively:

```
v1 = StringVector(1, 2)
print('current StringVector "x": ', StringVector.__dict__['x'].prop)
v2 = StringVector(3, 4)
print('current StringVector "x": ', StringVector.__dict__['x'].prop)

print(v1.x)
print(v2.x)
```

will have the following output:

```
Write
Write
current StringVector "x":  1
Write
Write
current StringVector "x":  3
Read
3.0
Read
3.0
```

I suppose this is not what you want=). To store unique value per object inside object, make the following changes:

```
class MyNewStringMemory(object):
    def __init__(self, convert, name):
        self.convert = convert
        self.name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Read')
        return self.convert(getattr(obj, self.name))

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Write')
        setattr(obj, self.name, str(val))

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        print('Delete')


class StringVector(Vector):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    x = MyNewStringMemory(float, 'x')
    y = MyNewStringMemory(float, 'y')


v1 = StringVector(1, 2)
v2 = StringVector(3, 4)

print(v1.x, type(v1.x))
print(v1._x, type(v1._x))
print(v2.x, type(v2.x))
print(v2._x, type(v2._x))
```

Output:

```
Write
Write
Write
Write
Read
Read
1.0 <class 'float'>
1 <class 'str'>
Read
Read
3.0 <class 'float'>
3 <class 'str'>
```

Also, you definitely could save data inside centralized store, using descriptor's `__set__` method.

Refer to this document: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Oh whoops, thanks a lot, didn't think about that... So in general OOP terms, the descriptors are static members of the class?

Comment: Yep. Also in Python they are not so static=) and could be added to a class and used with their child objects in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a generic convertor('convert') like you did, this is the way to go.

The biggest downside will be **performance** when you will need to create a lot of instances( I assumed you might, since the class called `Vector`). This will be slow since python class initiation is slow.

In this case you might consider using [namedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) you can see the docs have a similar scenario as you have.

As a side note: If that possible, why not creating a dict with the string representation of x and y on the init method? and then keep using the x and y as normal variables without all the converting